# How to make sure change sets are persisted in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Change set is pretty useful for organizing unchecked-in changes, but when a change set is created, it is not persist immediately, which means if Eclipse dies later (Sometimes it has to be killed since some operation just won't finish and it doesn't respond to cancel), the newly created change set is lost, which is very annoying. So is there a way to ensure newly created change set is saved? Or alternatively, are there safer ways to organize changes not checked in to source control in Eclipse?